# Sending vcf does not work with gmail, but does with default mail app

Tags: android, email, gmail, vcf-vcard

I want to send a vcf file as an attachement in an email. This works with the default Mail app (on HTC One X) but not with the Gmail app.

The Gmail app does pop up and shows the mail to be sent including the vcf file as attachement. But when I press send then the app crashes and does not send the email.

When the attachement is not included the email is sent correctly. The vcf file is created by the app and is stored on the sd card. This is the code for sending the email:

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"email@gmail.com"});          
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "title");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "content");
File rootDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "exStorageDirectory");
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(rootDirectory + "/vcardFile.vcf");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);             
email.setType("text/vcard");
startActivity(email);
```

I have tried it with various setType inputs, but they don't seem to make a difference: `email.setType("message/rfc822");`
`email.setType("image/jpeg");`
`email.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");`
`email.setType("application/x-vcard");`
`email.setType("text/html");`
`email.setType("text/plain");`

The `screenshotUri` is made because without it the Gmail app crashes directly when it opens. The default Mail app also had no problem here.

Any ideas how to make this work with the Gmail app? 
Thanks for your help!